# AngularJS routing dont work on child folders

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-routing

Everything works except for the folder portfolio/acura when I go to the link it sends me to the portfolio page. but if i make i take out the "portfolio" and just makes it /acura it works just fine.

http://www.jaysg.com/#/portfolio/acura

// script.js

```
// create the module and name it scotchApp
    // also include ngRoute for all our routing needs
var site = angular.module('site', ['ngRoute', 'ngAnimate']);

// configure our routes
site.config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider

        // route for the home page
        .when('/', {
            templateUrl : 'templates/home.html',
            controller  : 'mainController'
        })
        .when('/home', {
            templateUrl : 'templates/home.html',
            controller  : 'mainController'
        })

        // route for the about page
        .when('/about', {
            templateUrl : 'templates/about.html',
            controller  : 'aboutController'
        })

        // route for the about page
        .when('/portfolio', {
            templateUrl : 'templates/portfolio.html',
            controller  : 'portfolioController'
        })

        // route for the subfolder this is what dont work
        .when('portfolio/acura', {
            templateUrl : 'templates/portfolio/acuransx/acura.html',
            controller  : 'acuransxController'
        })



        // route for the contact page
        .when('/contact', {
            templateUrl : 'templates/contact.html',
            controller  : 'contactController'
        })
        .otherwise({redirectTo:'/home'});

    ;


});
```

Comment: What link are you using?

Comment: http://www.jaysg.com/#/portfolio/acura

Comment: what the hell.... now it's working... i recached the page and it works

Comment: Before did you try to manually type the url in

Comment: yea I did I typed it manually and it didn't work

Comment: Could be a server issue. Is index.html being returned

Comment: do you know any other more efficient way to add a content to a page. like what I have is a portfolio -> links to a photo but I want to keep the template the same way just to take out the portfolio gallery and once you click the picture it shows the full image within the same div.

Comment: You could have two divs. One with the gallery and one with the image and use ng-show to show/hide each div depending on which one you want to show.

Comment: @WayneEllery thanks I will try that.. do you know if the picture won't be loading to the page until u click ngshow?  I ask because the full images are about 500kb each and don't want to slow down the main portfolio page... sorry if I don't make much sense

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot the /

```
 .when('/portfolio/acura', { ...
```

Comment: did you place the <base> tag in the index.html file?